# Image Store that is Accessible by all Subsites in Site Collection

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, image, sharepoint-news

Is it possible to have a single location, in which I can store my images and access them from different subsites?

My aim is to be able to easily select them while I am creating News Articles in different subsites within the site collection.

This would be on a Modern/Online Sharepoint tenant.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit more things to add, from the doc Robert provide

> Adding an organization assets library will enable a content delivery
>   network (CDN) for your organization to provide fast and reliable
>   performance for shared assets. You'll be prompted to enable CDN for
>   each organization asset library you add. Vanity domains are currently
>   not supported.

Adding the CDN origin takes around 15 mins. After running the `Add-SPOOrgAssetsLibrary cmdlet` we can use `Get-SPOTenantCdnOrigins` cmdlet to check the status.

```
Get-SPOTenantCdnOrigins -CdnType Private
```

[image]

When the configuration pending is disappeared, then the process is done. And you can use the cmdlet to check if the library is successfully added.

```
Get-SPOOrgAssetsLibrary
```

Answer (score 4):

**Organization assets library** is a new feature for SharePoint Online that is just now rolling out. It solves exactly your problem:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/organization-assets-library

Answer (score 2):

A bit more things to add, from the answer Jerry provided:

It make take some time for new Org Assets Libraries to show up in the image picker.

The first one showed up very soon, but the second one I made has taken nearly an hour so far.
[image: pix - it happened]
[image: missing]